# Proof of Euclids' lemma

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If $p$ is a prime number and $p \mid ab$ then $p \mid a$ or $p\mid b$, for all integers $a$ and $b$.

> **The proof starts with:**
>
> Without loss of generality, suppose $\gcd(p,a)=1$ (otherwise we are
>   done)

**Why are we done when $\gcd(p,a) ≠ 1?$**

Comment: `Why are we done` Because $\gcd(p,a) \mid p$ and $\,p\,$ is a prime, so its only divisors are ...

Comment: Only divisors of p are 1 and p... I still don't see it

Comment: $\gcd(p,a) \ne 1 \implies \gcd(p,a) = p \implies p \mid a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $p$ is a prime number, if the $\gcd(p,a)\neq 1$ then it must be the case that $\gcd(p,a)= p$, which means in particular that $p|a$. Since that was one of the conclusions we were shooting for, that case of the proof is handled. Thus, we skip that part by saying "without loss of generality suppose $\gcd(p,a)= 1$".

Answer (score 0):

To prove that $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$ is to prove that *if* $p\nmid a$ *then* $p\mid b$. And, since $p$ is prime, to assert that $p\nmid a$ is to assert that $\gcd(p,a)=1$.